# React Native app flashing white after launch screen on iOS 11

Tags: ios, react-native, ios11, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

We have more than 5 React Native apps published apps, and all app flashes to white between the launch screen and the first screen of the app. This creating wired behaviour and only noticeable on iOS 11.

We are using [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) for navigation. I believe this issue is related to `react-navigation` because apps like [UberEATS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubereats-food-delivery/id1058959277?mt=8) and [Airbnb](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airbnb/id401626263?mt=8), which are also developed with React-Native are working fine. These apps have their own navigation library I think.

Anyone else noticed this problem? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: I'm having this issue, have you find a solution for it ?

Comment: I believe custom splash screen will fix this issue, try this [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen)

Comment: I tried [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) and it fixed the issue.

Comment: [This answer to a question about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46642754/1277350) suggests setting the rootView background. Good option if you don't necessarily want a splash screen plugin.

Comment: try this :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51453100/5461400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by adding custom splash screen, credits goes to [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen).

> This issue is fixed in **Xcode 9.2**.