# React Native white flash after splash screen on iOS: Official solution not working, throwing error (why??)

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm having the problem is describe in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636842/app-flashing-white-after-launch-screen-on-ios-11/46642754#46642754) post but the solutions provided and even the [solution](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device#pro-tip) provided in the Facebook docs are throwing and uncaught error (**NSException**). The error throws at this line of the official Facebook solution:

```
launchScreenView.frame = self.window.bounds;
```

The full solution is to add the following code to **AppDelegate.m**:

```
// Place this code after "[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]" and before "return YES;"
UIView* launchScreenView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LaunchScreen" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
launchScreenView.frame = self.window.bounds;
rootView.loadingView = launchScreenView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) and it works beautifully! Just used it exactly as described!